# Can I have partial template specialization with the using keyword?

Tags: c++11, templates, using

In the code of the [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/097d81363befbce1bf922379a4ea886e5f6dbd2b/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L332) library I find this:

```
template<typename _Tp, int cn> class Vec
{
  ...
}

typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i;
typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef Vec<float, 2> Vec2f;
typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
```

I would like to have a `Vec` of type `float` and variable length `N`. Is it possible to write something like

```
using Vecf<N> = Vec<float, N>;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you are nearly there.
The correct syntax would be

```
template<int N>
using Vecf = Vec<float, N>;
```

Comment: That means, if I use `Vec<N>` as a member in a class, this class needs to be templated as well - which propagates all the way up?

Comment: Yes, templates need all information at compile time, so you need some way to provide it. This site might be interesting to you [type_alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)